# Filtering an array of objects containing an array in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to search through an array to return objects based on a user's search text. Below are the data structures I am using. I'm using a searchBar to get the searchText

```
var objects = [SomeObject]()      //array of objects

var filteredObject = [SomeObject]()  //filtered array
var isSearching = false

struct SomeObject {
    var sectionName: String
    var sectionObjects : [History]
}

struct History {
    var firstName: string
    var lastName: Int
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredObject = objects.filter({ (obj: SomeObject) -> Bool in
            return obj.sectionObjects.filter { $0.firstName?.contains(searchText.lowercased()) as! Bool}
        })
        isSearching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I want my `filteredObject` to return objects with the sectionObjects `firstName` containing the searchText. The `searchBar function` is where the filtering is taking place.

Comment: Nothing in your code is a dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `sectionObjects` is empty

```
filteredObject = objects.filter({ (obj: SomeObject) -> Bool in
     return !obj.sectionObjects.filter { $0.firstName.contains(searchText.lowercased())}.isEmpty
})
```

But instead of the inner `filter`, it is better you use `contains`.

```
obj.sectionObjects.contains { $0.firstName.contains(searchText.lowercased()) != nil}
```

Comment: Better use `contains()`, it should stop at first match instead of checking `isEmpty`.

Comment: `obj.sectionObjects.contains { $0.firstName.contains(searchText.lowercased()) != nil}` Xcode was complaining until I added `!= nil` at the end. Thanks for your help

Comment: I want the `sectionObjects` to be filtered also so filter should be used instead of contains

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to consider the case that the text field is empty to cancel the search.

Second of all basically you have to check, if (at least) one `firstName` of the items in `sectionObjects` contains the search string. So the outer function does `filter` and the inner checks for  <strike>`first`</strike>  `contains`.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        isSearching = false
        filteredObject.removeAll()
    } else {
        filteredObject = objects.filter({ object -> Bool in
            return object.sectionObjects.contains{ $0.firstName.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
        })
        isSearching = true
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Side note:

`$0.firstName?.contains(searchText.lowercased()` returns **`false`** if `firstName` is **John** and you search for **Jo**. However `range(of` with `caseInsensitive` option searches case insensitive on both sides.

Comment: Why note use `contains(where:)` istead of `first(where:) != nil`? Any reason I'm missing?

Comment: Just habit. `contains(where` has been introduced much later than `first(where`. But I think there is not a big difference with regard to performance.

Comment: I think the performance is the same, it's just more about readability nitpick.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: The sectionObjects needs to be filtered also